# Can a URLSessionStreamTask be used for both reading and writing?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiontask

In the `startLoading` method of my `URLProtocol` subclass, I create a `URLSession` and `URLSessionStreamTask`.  I `resume` the task and add a `BlockOperation` to call my first transaction method.  That method uses `URLSessionStreamTask.write`.  If I don't get an error, another `BlockOperation` is placed with my second transaction method.  That method uses `URLSessionStreamTask.read` and it always times out.

The error looked like:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x10945dff0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=gopher://www.floodgap.com:80/GET%20/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=gopher://www.floodgap.com:80/GET%20/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Can a stream-task only be used for one I/O call?  Or only just writing or just reading?  Or is there some mode-switch function I forgot to call between the write and read?  Could there be another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add read block operation before write to the streamTask. Read and write are asynchron calls, waiting until timeout happens. 
In your example you send a command with write, I guess it receives and answer very quick, before adding read to the task is done. So you never see your response.